# quandry with errorlevel in a read loop

Tags: loops, autohotkey, errorlevel

Im having trouble setting error level in an autohotkey script.

As of now, it works fine unless the putty session closes unexpectedly.

I am calling a sub after setting ip and password to reboot equipment via telnet.

Basically I need a message box to pop up and a return command instead of a crash

like 
MsgBox, reboot of %IP% failed
return

havent been able to get it to work myself, so figured i'd ask here

```
Proximreboot:
{
SetKeyDelay, 10, 10
Run, C:\Program Files\PuTTY\putty.exe -load "script" telnet://%IP%, , , NewPID ; ------------run putty.exe also get a new PID
WinWaitActive, ahk_pid %NewPID%

Loop ;---------------------------- loop to look for password prompt in putty
{
Loop, read, C:\Program Files\PuTTY\%IP%.script.log ;----------loop to read the log file
    last_line := A_LoopReadLine

IfInString, last_line, password
{
break
}

}

ControlSend, ,%PASS%{Enter},ahk_pid %NewPID%, , , 
Sleep, 1000
ControlSend, ,reboot 30{Enter},ahk_pid %NewPID%, , , 
Sleep, 1563
ControlSend, ,exit{Enter},ahk_pid %NewPID%, , , 
Sleep, 1000
filedelete, C:\Program Files\PuTTY\*.script.log
last_line := blank
}
return
```

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured it out

```
Loop
{
Process, Exist, %NewPID%

Loop, read, C:\Program Files\PuTTY\%IP%.script.log
    last_line := A_LoopReadLine

IfInString, last_line, password
{
break
}
if !errorlevel 
{ 
    MsgBox, Reboot of %IP% Failed.
    Return
}
}
```

I don't know if I'm happier that I figured it out, or that a device timed out the first time I tested it.